# Is there a way to run an inline node javascript in command line?

Tags: node.js

I want to temporarily run the node javascript.
For example, like this:

```
echo console.log(1+1) > tmp.js & node tmp.js & del tmp.js
```

It works fine.
However, I do not like the use of temporary files.
Is there any other cleaner way?

For example, I wonder if there is an option for such a function in node.exe

Comment: You can use the `-e, --eval` option: `node -e "console.log(1+1)"` 
 Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script

Comment: @mdker Write that as an answer

Comment: In general you don't need temporary files for things like this on Linux. Node, like any sane scripting language, enters a REPL when invoked without a file. Therefore you can pipe commands to it: `echo 'console.log(1+1)' | node`. This works for other REPL interpreters like **bash, tcl, ksh, python** etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `-e, --eval` option:
`node -e "console.log(1+1)"`

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script